# If I have an event listener on an HTML element, how do I get the value of the child element that I clicked on when there are multiple children

Tags: javascript, html, events, parent-child, addeventlistener

I would like to preface this by saying I am quite new to Javascript.

I am trying to make a website that has multiple journal entries that each have a title and description. I have an event listener on a section tag that contains all of the entries, and then article tags within which have a value associated with them and contain the individual entries. I want to be able to click a specific entry and get the value of the article tag for the clicked entry.

So far all the methods I have tried have given a value of null.

Here is the relevant HTML code

```
<div id="displayById"></div>
<section id="timeline" class ="grid">

<!--   entries cards for  testing layout  -->
<article value = "1">
    <p class="entryDate">20.09.2021</p>
    <h3 class="entryTitle">Entry 1 Title</h3> 
    <img  class="entryImg" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
    <div class="entryDescription">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>

</article>
<article value = "2">
    <h3 class="entryTitle">Entry 2 Title</h3>
    <img  class="entryImg" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
    <div class="entryDescription">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</article>    
</section>
```

And here is the Javascript where the event listener and subsequent function is

```
const selectEntry = document.getElementById('timeline')
selectEntry.addEventListener('click', entryById)

function entryById(e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault()
        let id = e.target.closest('article').value
        console.log(id)
        document.getElementById('timeline').style.display="none"
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/entry/${id}`)
        .then( r => r.json())
        .then( data => {
            console.log(data)
            let entry = `<article class="card" value = ${id}>
            <h3 class="entryTitle">${data['title']}</h3>
            <img  class="entryImg" src="" alt="">
            <div class="entryDescription">${data['description']}</div>
        </article>`
        document.getElementById('displayById').insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', entry)
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }
}
```

I have tried using forEach to add an event listener for each article but I couldn't get that to work. My most recent attempt is using

> let id = e.target.closest('article').value

to select the closest article and get the value, but this makes id equal to null. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong or a better method to do this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Article elements don't have the `value` attribute, so you won't be able to use the `value` property either. Use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dataset`instead of value as attribute.
With data set you could do something like `data-value=999` and get the value in javascript using 'element.dataset.value'

Comment: Ah great that worked, I didn't realise article tags didn't have the value attribute

Answer (score 0):

I would attach the event listener to the articles themselves rather than trying to drill down from the `section` and identify which article was clicked. Maybe you weren't working with an array when you tried attaching event listeners to the articles?

```
const articles = document.querySelectorAll('#timeline article');
Array.from(articles).forEach( article => {
    article.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems like a much cleaner method, I will try this.